# Does Socket.io 'combine' packets if sent at nearly the same time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

For example, if a NodeJS server has the following code:

```
socket.emit('msg', { data: 'abc123' });
socket.emit('msg', { data: 'aaaaa' });
socket.emit('another_event', { data: 'ooooo' });
socket.emit('yet_another_event', { data: '555' });
```

Will there always be 4 separate packets sent to the client? Or will Socket.io attempt to 'combine' the packets into a single packet, and then Socket.io on the client side will 'separate' the single packet so they get handled by their proper `io.on()` listeners?

Comment: whoever connected/opened this node file will be sent to across.

For example: assume that the node js running at localhost:3000, if you open in several tabs in one browser the emit will be broadcast to all the tab.

Comment: I'm just talking about the server emitting those 4 messages to a single client

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question in full.

What socket.io does is 'multiplexing' these packets, meaning that all of them will be sent through the same channel. 
These packets are not sent at the same time / not combined in a single packet for different reasons. One, it's risky in terms of bandwidth. What if you have 5 packets of 50kb each? In case of network failure or packet loss, you lose the entire 5 packets rather than one. Now this is not a problem, however in case we are speaking of packets of higher size, then it becomes a problem.

By the nature of transmission, packets should be transmitted serially. Something that may interest you is that these packets sometimes do not arrive in the same order, however they are reassembled by a protocol. In case of TCP/IP, these packets will be reassembled before being forwarded to the application.

You may want to learn about [connectionless vs connection-oriented](https://www.linktionary.com/c/connections.html) to understand whether you need to send all packets or, they can be sent separately.